# Solve the following proofs

Tags: probability, statistics

Let A1,A2,...,An be events in the sample space Ω with probability measure P. Show that
a) P (A1 ∪ A2 ∪ · · · ∪ An) ≤ P (A1) + P (A2) + · · · + P (An); 
b) P (A1 ∩ A2 ∩ · · · ∩ An) ≥ P (A1) + P (A2) + · · · + P (An) − (n − 1);
c) If P(Ai)=1 for all i=1,2,...,n then P(A1 ∩A2 ∩···∩An)=1.

This is how I solved a), but i can't do b) or c)

P(A1 ∪ B)= P(A1) + P(B) - P(A1∩B) ≤ P(A1) + P(B)
let B = A2 ∪ A3, then
P(B) ≤ P(A2) + P(A3)
So P(A1 ∪ A2 ∪ A3) ≤ P(A1) + P(A2) + P(A3)

Answer (score 1):

$P\left(A_{1}\cap\cdots\cap A_{n}\right)=1-P\left(A_{1}^{c}\cup\cdots\cup A_{n}^{c}\right)\geq1-\left(P\left(A_{1}^{c}\right)+\cdots+P\left(A_{n}^{c}\right)\right)$
according to a) and $P\left(A_{i}^{c}\right)=1-P\left(A_{i}\right)$. This should
do it for b). If you apply b) for $P\left(A_{i}\right)=1$ then you find c).

Comment: @mrf Thank you for this. If they do it again then I will just delete my answer.